# Resource recommendations: Levy process estimation using programming languages

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, reference-request, estimation

Perhaps this type of question is not very suitable for this forum, but I'll try to make my question a little useful.

I'm studying stochastic processes, more precisely, Levy processes. A Levy process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is characterized by its characteristic function given by:
$$\log \varphi_{X_t}(u)= t\left(ib'u+ \frac{u'a u}{2} + \int_{\mathbb R^d - \{0\}} \left[ e^{i u'x} - 1 - i u'x \mathbf{1}_{(|x|\leq 1)}
 \right] \nu(dx)\right)$$
More precisely, the whole process is characterized by the triple $(a,b, \nu)$.

A good but extremely technical book is [Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus](https://www.cambridge.org/us/universitypress/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/levy-processes-and-stochastic-calculus-2nd-edition). However, I am interested in estimating the triple $(a,b, \nu)$. Note that the drift $b\in\mathbb R^d$ and the matrix $a$ are finite dimensional parameters and, consequently, could be estimated with parametric techniques. On the other hand, the Levy measure $\nu$ might require non-parametric techniques.

So I'm looking for bibliographical references that help me in the computational part and implementation of the estimation of $(a,b, \nu)$.

The first chapter of book [Lévy Matters IV](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-12373-8) looks like a good book to me, but it's the only decent reference I've found. Also, maybe it's not as suitable for someone who doesn't have a lot of experience in the subject. So I would like to have suggestions for books with a more practical approach and, perhaps, using some language (R, python or some other).

Can you help me?

Comment: [This question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/what-are-the-quantitative-finance-books-that-we-should-all-have-in-our-shelves) has a decent number of resources listed.

Comment: Wow, the list is interesting and comprehensive. Thank you for sharing. If you have any specific recommendations on how to estimate (preferably using a programming language) the Levy measure $\nu$, please feel free to suggest one. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should start from estimating a more specific Levy process like GBM or Poisson process. It's likely hard to estimate a process at that level of generality.

Comment: This is related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59040/which-references-would-be-useful-as-an-introduction-to-econometrics-as-it-pertai/59045#59045.